# cache a dataframe in pyspark

Tags: caching, pyspark

I want to know more precisely about the use of the method cache for dataframe in pyspark

When I run `df.cache()` it returns a dataframe. 
Therefore, if I do `df2 = df.cache()`, which dataframe is in cache ? Is it `df`, `df2`, or both ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I found the source code [`DataFrame.cache`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/dataframe.html#DataFrame.cache)

```py
def cache(self):
    """Persists the :class:`DataFrame` with the default storage level (`MEMORY_AND_DISK`).

    .. note:: The default storage level has changed to `MEMORY_AND_DISK` to match Scala in 2.0.
    """
    self.is_cached = True
    self._jdf.cache()
    return self
```

Therefore, the answer is : **both**