# Pyspark:Need to understand the behaviour of cache in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to understand the behavior of cache in `pyspark`

1. Is `df.cache()` anyway different that `df = df.cache()` ?
2. Is it absolutely necessary to unpersist the cached dataframe at the end of program execution, I understand its cleared by spark based on (Least Recently used mechanism),and what can be negative impacts if I don't unpersist a dataframe, I can think of out of memory issues but need inputs
3. Is it possible that when I use `df = df.cache()`, the re-execution of the program uses the old cached data, rather than recalculating and overriding the cached dataframe ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cache a dataframe in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47639386/cache-a-dataframe-in-pyspark)

Comment: Thank a lot @Steven ,It clears most of my concepts, Can you please throw some light on point 2 as well, I am a bit confused about the usage of unpersist .I have cached few dataframes and If I don't unpersist them at the end of execution of program and rerun the program, will the old cached dataframe be overriden and stored at the same memory space or will it occupy a new memory space(considering its not pushed out based LRU). And Is it possible that spark doesn't calculate the dataframe again at all on program re-execution as it already can find it in the cached memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to unpersist at the end. stopping spark will clear the cached dataframes.
You cannot persist from one spark execution to another one. If you want to "persist" from one Spark to another, the only solution is to physically save your data (write) and read them again at the next execution.